# Java bitmap compositing how to

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm porting an AS3 (Flash) application to Java Android. And I need an equivalent function to this prototype:
copyPixels(sourceBitmapData:BitmapData, sourceRect:Rectangle, destPoint:Point, alphaBitmapData:BitmapData = null, alphaPoint:Point = null, mergeAlpha:Boolean = false):void

The important parameters are SourceBitmap, SourceRect, DestPoint and MergeAlpha, I don't need the other parameters. Right now I'm using Bitmap class in Java, is it possible to have such a function with Bitmap class that is reasonably fast to overcome Android Java poor performance?

Maybe I should use BufferedImage or something else but I'm lost because Java has a lot of Image/Bitmap whatever Class that performs similar duty while AS3 only have 2. I haven't found some code that does what I want without resorting to some form of Canvas class which I want to avoid because of performance issues with Java Android. There is CopyPixels function in Bitmap class but from what I understand it does not composite alpha values. I'm sure there is some code somewhere that does what I do and hope I won't have to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks for answers/comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the android.graphics.Bitmap class. The Android canvas is actually very efficient. It is just a wrapper that allows you to do basic drawing on a bitmap. If you take a look at some of the openGL examples, drawing is usually faster using canvas than openGL in Java. What were the performance issues? Maybe SO can help solve those problems.

Also, you could do it yourself by iterating through the pixels in the bitmap and blending colors yourself. It's not very difficult, but really the performance there is not going to be much different than the Canvas class.

Comment: I surely believe Canvas is faster than OpenGl but using Canvas as a placeholder to composite graphics is slow. That's because you need to copy both bitmap to canvas then copy them back again to bitmap. Copying bitmap to bitmap with alpha compositing (working with buffers not individual pixels) would be the best solution if possible. The performance issues were slow framerate, hang ups when the Java GC does it's job, flickering on screen etc... The kinds of problems you do not have with C++ when you push a lot of pixels. Thanks for comment, it's useful to know Canvas is not a bottleneck.

Comment: You actually don't have to copy a lot. Use the Canvas constructor that takes a Bitmap, or call SetBitmap(). These shouldn't copy the bitmap. It should just mutate the bitmap pixels. What do you mean about copying the bitmaps? Why are the GC's taking too long? Are you creating and recycling bitmaps every frame?

Comment: The application has to copy millions of pixels from bitmap to bitmap, it's just written this way and I need to port it without changing everything. What I mean by copying the bitmap is this according to your method: Canvas throwAway = new Canvas(Bitmap1); throwAway.drawBitmap(bitmap2); and after that I need to get the data in throwAway Canvas back into Bitmap1 (I don't know how to that too). The problem here is that I need to re-copy Canvas into Bitmap. I also have to make sure Canvas is not invoking GC. I don't know why GC is slow, I never used a fast Java app, hear it was because GC.

Comment: OK I think I'm understanding now, if I draw on Canvas it modify the Bitmap. If I have to create new Canvas each time I want to copy, this is bad for GC. By the way 90% of the code is Static in the app, it's high performance stuff. I think I understand how to do it now though. 1. create static Canvas 2. Canvas.setBitmap(bitmap1)  3. Canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2) after that for the next copy I can reuse Canvas with setBitmap without side effects. Only caveat is I think calling setBitmap does create objects by that function.

Comment: Yes canvas just modifies the data in place. You don't have to copy from the canvas back to Bitmap1. You don't need to reuse the canvas. The canvas object shouldn't be what's causing problems. The canvas object is very small size in memory because it's just a wrapper to a bitmap that exposes lots of useful functions. Instead you should reuse the bitmaps. Use the copyPixels() method you already saw to copy new data for each frame. You shouldn't create a new Bitmap object every frame. Allocating larges chunks of memory is slow, and it has caused you OutOfMemoryExceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much, this will do. I still have framerate issues with drawing 2 simple sprites but I guess it can't be helped without the NDK. Since all Java applications lag on my 100$ android tablet, the user of such device will probably just swallow it up.